# Should I use the Gaussian process on data that may exhibit regimes/mixtures?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, markov-process, gaussian-process

I have a data set that is highly negatively skewed. I first used OLS to probe the data set and I noticed that regressing (y = bX + e | y > 0) and (y = bX + e | y < 0) gives very different results, where some of the coefficients in b have opposite signs depending on whether y > 0 or y < 0. So I suspect there is non-linearity/regimes in the data. I know that GPs are very powerful in representing non-linearity so the question is whether I should use GP or a Gaussian mixture/Markov regime switching regression?

p.s. At this stage I'm not sure if the state switching is smooth.

Comment: Since $E(y \mid y>0, X)\neq E(y \mid y<0, X)$, isn't it to be expected that the regressions give different results? Regime switching would typically be changing based on values of $X$?

Comment: Isn't it more like E(b|X,y>0) != E(b|X,y<0)? If the relationship is linear, theoretically you'd expect b to be similar when you regress solely on y>0 and y<0. From what I'm seeing some of the signs in b_i actually flips

Comment: No, I meant $E(y\mid \ldots)$, the thing the regression is estimating (and I don't know how to interpret $E(b\mid X,y>0)$) However, try the following experiment: simulate $X\sim N(2,1)$, $y=X+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon\sim N(0,1)$ and fit (without intercept) OLS regressions $y=bX$  wit the datapoints $y>0$ and with the datapoints $y<0$  - the sign of the coefficient switches sign while there are no "regime switches" in this data.  ( And even with intercept added, I get the slope to switch sign at least by using a long-tailed error distribution )

Comment: Just to check I didn't misunderstand the notation: (y = bX + e | y>0) means you discard all datap-oints where $y<=0$ and fit the OLS regression using the remaining data? (Vice versa for (y = bX + e | y < 0))

Comment: Yep, so I'm regressing positive y's and negative y's separately, to see whether the relationship holds for positive-half and negative-half of y. I repeated your experiment with $X \sim N(0,2)$ so it's centered on zero. I then regress without intercept for positive y and negative y. For negative y, $b = 0.70$. For positive y, $b = 0.87$. They are not the same because of randomness but the idea is given sufficient data points, if the relationship is linear then regressing on a subset of the data should give you the same outcome.

Comment: Do you have a proof for that claim? (When you select subsets based on $y$ rather than $X$? ) Since the regression is modeling $y$ as a function $X$ I don't understand what it would even mean that the relation is different for different regions of _$y$_ (except that selecting based on $y$ somewhat acts as a selection based on $X$)   (In the fully symmetric experiment you performed it seems to me due to symmetry the coefficients will be the same but note that they are different than the full regression )